# Student's T-Distribution problem clarification

Tags: statistics

My Statistics Text asks the following:

Consider a $t$-distribution $T$ with 8 degrees of freedom

$(a)$ Find $t_{0.025}$ so that $P(−t_{0.025} ≤ T ≤ t_{0.025}) = 0.95$.
I found this to be $t=2.306004$

Now this is where I am confused

$(b)$ Solve the inequality $[−t_{0.025} ≤ T ≤ t_{0.025}]$ so that $μ$ is
in the middle.

What does the author mean by "in the middle". Any insights much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very vague as it stands, but from context it's relatively clear what they must be asking.

Presumably, $T$ is defined as $$ T = \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar x-\mu)}{\hat{\sigma}}$$ where $\bar x$ and $\hat \sigma$ are the sample mean and standard deviation. So you can rewrite the inequality as $$ -t_{\alpha} < \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar x-\mu)}{\hat{\sigma}} < t_\alpha$$ where $\alpha = .025.$

By 'put $\mu$ in the middle' they mean to rewrite this as and inequality of the form $a<\mu<b.$

To do this, look at the inequalities separately. $$ \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar x-\mu)}{\hat{\sigma}} < t_\alpha$$ can be solved to get $$\mu >\bar x-\frac{t_\alpha\hat\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$ and the other one gives $$\mu <\bar x+\frac{t_\alpha\hat\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$.

So the inequality is $$\bar x-\frac{t_\alpha\hat\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}<\mu <\bar x+\frac{t_\alpha\hat\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

(This gives the $1-2\alpha$ confidence interval for $\mu.$)

Comment: That is what I suspected I just thought that was a very strange way of saying that for a math textbook. Thanks a lot.